# Database field with multiple allowed value types

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I am using `Fluent NHibernate` in my ASP.NET MVC Application to retrieve and save data to a `Postgresql` database.

Say you have a table which holds

```
Fields {Name, DataType, Value}

//Model
public class Table {

    public virtual string Name { get; set;}

    public virtual string DataType { get; set;}

    public virtual string Value { get; set;}
}
```

So a typical records could be:

```
Record { "Firstname", "Varchar", "Bob" }
Record { "DateOfBirth", "Timestamp", "2003-04-12 04:05:06" }
```

So in order for this to work all, value needs to be of type `Varchar`.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't like the idea that `Value` is type `string` / `Varchar`.

I would prefer the value type to be of type `object` or something. I have tried this but got an `Exception` from `Fluent NHibernate`.

How would you approach this problem from a DDD perspective?

Comment: I don't know about postgresql, but I have used this exact strategy with a table in MSSQL in production with success in the past.  SQL doesn't give you an "object" datatype to work with, so the next best thing I have found is serialized objects in a varchar column, with a second column to store the data type.  Maybe someone else will have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a json (or jsonb if your postgres version supports it).

I wouldn't do that in this case. In order to get the best use out of indexes and data searching, it'd be best to come up with a structure that kept the different data types in different fields, so they could be sorted on and searched efficiently.

An example:

```
create table obj as (obj_id serial,
                     name varchar,
                     vc_data varchar,
                     ts_data timestamp,
                     intdata integer
                     datatype varchar);
```

You can create an index on all the fields if necessary, and even a view to make 
some of your code more simple (when not searching or ordering by datatype)

```
create view obj_view as
  (select obj_id,
   name,
   coalesce(vc_data, ts_data, int_data) data
   from obj)
```

Comment: `json` supports PostgreSQL 9.2 and above,`jsonb` supports PostgreSQL 9.4 and above

Comment: The view would work well for querying as is, but you will have to change your application logic for your insert/update/delete